# Codeigniter pagination query string in first page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am using CI pagination class.

when i am on any page different from page 1 (with filtering) my URL would look like this:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/search/interests=5%2C23%2C12%2C13&fulldate=&location=/2
```

On page 1 it would show me:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/search/
```

And the filtering would still be fine, so it just hides the query string and the page number.

I noticed that when I go to page 2, then go back to page 1, that the URL is correct.

I need the URL on the first page to also be like this:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/search/interests=5%2C23%2C12%2C13&fulldate=&location=/1
```

The relevant part in the controller function looks like this:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
        $data['all_vacancies'] = $this->vacancies_model->getFilteredVacanciesOverview($filterdata);
        if(!array_filter($filterdata)) {
            $pagconfig['base_url'] = base_url().VACANCY_OVERVIEW;
        } else {
            $pagconfig['base_url'] = base_url().VACANCY_OVERVIEW . http_build_query($filterdata);
        }
        $pagconfig['first_url'] = '1';
        $pagconfig['total_rows'] = count($data['all_vacancies']);
        $pagconfig['per_page'] = 3;
        if (LOCATION) {
            if (is_numeric($this->uri->segment(3))) {
                $pagconfig['uri_segment']  = 3;
            } else {
                $pagconfig['uri_segment']  = 4;
            }
        } else {
            if (is_numeric($this->uri->segment(2))) {
                $pagconfig['uri_segment']  = 2;
            } else {
                $pagconfig['uri_segment']  = 3;
            }
        }

        $pagconfig['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $this->pagination->initialize($pagconfig);
        $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

the link in my nav menu looks like this:

```
<a href="<?=site_url('vrijwilligerswerk/', $link_protocol )?>" class="nav-link">
   <span><?=lang("nav_dashboard_vacancy_overview")?></span>
</a>
```

and my routes.php file looks like this:

```
$route['^vrijwilligerswerk'] = 'dashboard/vacancy/overviewVacancies';
$route['^vrijwilligerswerk/(:num)'] = 'dashboard/vacancy/overviewVacancies/null/null/$1';
$route['^vrijwilligerswerk/(:any)'] = 'dashboard/vacancy/overviewVacancies/null/$1';
$route['^vrijwilligerswerk/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'dashboard/vacancy/overviewVacancies/null/$1/$2';
```

I tried playing around with the answers in different topics like for example:

```
$pagconfig['first_url'] = '1';
```

or put the following on true in Pagination class file:

```
protected $reuse_query_string = TRUE;
```

But neither of those shows the query string on page 1

Comment: You're doing it wrong. The query string always goes after all of the other URI segments, and is preceeded by a question mark. Right now it looks like you are attempting to insert the query string into URI segment 2.

Comment: Isn't it the default behavior of the pagination to put the pagenumber at the end? how do i change this?

Comment: Pagination config has a "uri_segment" that you can set. Documentation says that the class will try to automatically determine which segment is for pagination, but because your query string isn't formed properly it probably doesn't recognize your query string as a query string. A query string should start with a question mark.